# How can I give the number two decimal in my template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I use the total_prices in my template

```
{{ data.total_prices }}  # there shows 300
```

But how can I give it both float number?

I means it looks like `300.00` in template.

How to do with that?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [floatformat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat) template filter,

```
{{ data.total_prices|floatformat:-2 }}  # now it shows 300.00
```